Find unused symfony services
The project I'm working on has right now 7710 services. Autowiring is enabled and paths were not always excluded from autowiring, so right now we have a lot of services, which I'm sure, are not used as a service.
The big problem with that is the container build time.
Is there a way to find unused services?
Symfony 4.3/PHP 7.4
P.S.:
I already started with a small php script to read the container xml. Perhaps someone can point me to the right direction: https://gist.github.com/dr0bz/0fd18255f5a5c3b6b17ab3e8152be225. It finds a lot of false positives. Although it helped to get rid of about 400 services right now.

Keep in mind that both Symfony 4.3 and PHP 7.4 are horribly outdated. Maybe updating to supported versions can already help to speed up the container compilation?

Yes i know. Also LTS is out right now. For sure php 8 and also new sf version would make a log, but there is no capacity to update it:(

Have you debugged the container service after all services have been initialised? Perhaps you can recognise which service is not required by its properties.

Look at my comment to the answer. I think that should do it.

Please check Container Compilation docs (here for Symfony 4.x): https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html
Removing unused services is one of its features, among other ways of avoiding auto-wiring runtime overhead.

Ha! That's a good one. I've found out now that there is a log file where removed services are logged. Example:
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RemoveUnusedDefinitionsPass: Removed service "App\SomeClass...."; reason: unused.
I've found about 1000 of such entries there. Thats a good starting point. I could parse it and generate a list of excludes for services.yaml file. It's almost 12 percent of all services.
Thank you.
